# Animation not overriding height in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I designed a simple form. It's working fine on Chrome, Opera, FF. But on Edge there seems to be some issue.
**What I have done is assigned a class to a form which is increasing its size from 0 to auto (besides scaling it up).**
 However Edge is not doing this. When I saw in dev tools and removed height=0; from code, it started working fine but well that's not what I want.

**HTML:**

```
  <h1 style="text-align:center" id="heading">Form Design</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="boxed" id="form">
        <h3 style="text-align:center; margin: 4% 0 9% 0;" id="greeting"
        .
        .
        .
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-
         outline-primary" style="font-weight: bold" disabled>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boxed{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid var(--new);
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);

  /* animation-name: open; */
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.68,.65,.37,1);
  animation-delay: 0.3s;

  height: 0;
}

@keyframes open {
  0%   {height:0; -webkit-transform: scaleY(0); transform: scaleY(0);}
  100% {height:auto; -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); transform: scaleY(1);}
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).ready(function play(){
  $('.boxed').css('animation-name','open');
  $('.boxed').css('-webkit-animation-name','open');
  $('#bg').css('opacity','0.6');
  $('.boxed').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',function(){
    $('#greeting').css('opacity','1');
    $('input.form-control, select').css('opacity','1');
    $('.btn').css('opacity','1');
  });
.
.
.
```

Now I know animation is running since onanimationend stuff is running, so what's the problem here?
BTW, I have uploaded this stuff here : **https://iam-shivam.github.io/Form/index.html**
Try running site on Edge and some other browser, you'll know the difference!

Comment: caniuse.com lists some known issues and examples: https://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `animation`, use Javascript to add a class that applies CSS styles and CSS3 transitions

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  $(".box").addClass("open"); 
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: seagreen;
  transition: width .4s ease 0s, height .8s ease .4s;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box.open {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but when you set   height: auto;  things go haywire and transitions don't work anymore.That's the reason I went on with animations to get that done.